# Diablo 2 & Wine Compatibility

Tags: diablo-ii, wine

I was just wondering if anyone has any experience installing & running Diablo 2 on Linux (Ubuntu 10, latest Wine) using Wine? I tried to install the other day and encountered a problem, but I think that was due to my slightly decrepit cd-rom.

EDIT : The file that it failed on was "d2video.mpq" on the cinematics disc. :(

Comment: Depends on how much you drink :D

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit, but your name is already stated at the bottom of your question, no need to repeat it in the body... See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) and [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @Tobias, Not a problem, its just my typing autopilot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the Diablo II installer from the Blizzard site and was able to install it under Wine 1.3.15 on Ubuntu 11.04 without issues.  If you run into issues while using CDs, don't forget that you can add your game serial number to a Battle.net account and download it.

One annoying issue was holding ctrl would move the window instead of showing all dropped items.  I believe you can change this from the winecfg options.

Comment: Attempting download now...

Answer (score 2):

The WineHQ application compatibility database has some information here:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=74

The retail version seems to work well.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=49

> **What works**
>
> Everything (Gameplay, videos, loggin in, battle.net)
>
> Sound works better after updating from 1.12 to 1.13
>
> **What does not**
>
> Nothing that I can think of
>
> **What was not tested**
>
> Nothing that I can think of

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your install issue is related to the game disc itself.

According to [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=315), D2: LOD runs on Ubuntu 11.04 with a platinum rating (Which indicates "*Applications which install and run flawlessly on an out-of-the-box Wine installation*"). Vanilla D2 gets a [similar rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=49) running on Ubuntu 10.04.

It sounds like you have your original CD Key so I would recommend using Battle.net to turn your CD Key into a digital download, then redownload the game via the Blizzard downloader (which [also runs under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13491), of course).

Comment: Attempting download now...